# How can I prevent TeX hyphenating one occurrence of a word (locally)?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I'm currently typesetting a test using the `exam` class and the test consists of some True or False statements. Some statements span a couple of lines, but some could fit in a single line, except for the last word, which is hyphenated, like so:

```
O momento angular de um sistema pode mudar sem a ação de torques ex-
ternos
```

I know I can *make* hyphenations by using `tor\-que`, but I would like to know if there is an opposite that works *locally*, i.e., not adding `\hyphenation{torque}` to the preamble because I may want this word hyphanated at some other point.

I know that `\mbox{…}` does the trick, but I'm not sure if it's a kludge and there's a better solution, specially without extra packages.

Ideas?

Comment: Use `\mbox{...}`, and that's that.

Comment: Have you -- or a package you've loaded -- maybe set up some extra hyphenation patterns? For instance, it may be OK to hyphenate `torque` and `torques` if Spanish or Portuguese hyphenation rules are in effect. In English, though, these two words should not be hyphenated.

Comment: To be precise, the text is in portuguese and the hyphenated word is "externos"

I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: `\mbox` is defined in LaTeX kernel as `\long\def\mbox#1{\leavevmode\hbox{#1}}` (better definition is `\def\mbox{\leavevmode\hbox}` but LaTeX kernel doesn't include the best definitions at many places). So you needn't any special packages. There is no better solution for protection of hyphenation of the word than `\hyphenation{word}` (globally for actual `\language`) or `\hbox{word}` (locally).

Comment: @wipet no, that would be a worse definition. The LaTeX definition is intentional.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What intention? I can't to write `\mbox to{}`, the verbatim in `\mbox` doesn't work. This is bad intention IMHO.

Comment: @wipet One of the aims of latex was to give a consistent syntax to the differing syntax of tex primitives. latex syntax is `makebox[..]{..}` not `to` , verbatim not working in arguments is a documented restriction, making it work in mbox makes the interface inconsistent and restricts possible redefinitions. latex209 \sbox for example didn't use `#1` but if people abused that and put verbatim there or delimited using `\bgroup` it fails when (say) color is used which needs to grab the argument. 2e made sure that all these commands had a consistent interface matching their documented behaviour

Answer (score 4):

The package [`hyphenat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat) provides a command `\nohyphens{}`, so that

```
O momento angular de um sistema pode mudar sem a ação de torques \nohyphens{externos}
```

should do the trick.

`\nohyphens` should be used for short parts of text. You should perhaps encapsulate the whole answer (statement?) in `\nohyphens{}`, but that depends on your content.

Comment: That's a nice solution, but I was curious about solutions requiring noa dittional packages.

Comment: ack, I just documented this solution for everybody else coming up with such a problem, finding this question and not having to hassle with "don't use no additional packages" due to artificial external restrictions.

Comment: Good point. This site _is_ for the community after all.